# How do I construct typed constants for the OneNote COM API in python?

Tags: python, com, ms-office, onenote

I want to use the `UpdatePageContent` COM method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853%28v=office.14%29.aspx) via the python `win32com` module. Things I can do so far include getting the hierarchy, getting page contents, etc. I can even validly manipulate the XML to prepare changes (tested using the MATLAB COM interface).

This is a minimal example of what I am trying to do:

```
    import win32com
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    oneNoteApp = win32com.client.Dispatch('OneNote.Application')
    pageID = '{603BD3F0-4DAB-4E5B-8E28-28CA0F2B0C83}{1}{B0}' # from GetHierarchy
    content = oneNoteApp.GetPageContent(pageID)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'xml')
    # ... modify xml (changes are valid and tested using MATLAB)
    oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(soup) # problem is here
```

Now this last line is tricky. According to the COM documentation all other arguments to `UpdatePageContent` are optional. However there seems to be an error in the bindings that `win32com` auto-generates. Called as in the example i get an error like

```
    C:\...\Temp\gen_py\3.4\0EA692EE-BB50-4E3C-AEF0-356D91732725x0x1x0.py in UpdatePageContent(self, bstrPageChangesXmlIn, dateExpectedLastModified, xsSchema, force)
        240     _prop_map_get_ = {
        241                 "COMAddIns": (104, 2, (9, 0), (), "COMAddIns", None),
    --> 242                 "Dummy1": (102, 2, (11, 0), (), "Dummy1", None),
        243                 "LanguageSettings": (105, 2, (9, 0), (), "LanguageSettings", None),
        244                 # Method 'Windows' returns object of type 'Windows'

    ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

So the `ExpectedDateLastModified` default argument seems to be broken. Passing an explicit zero like `oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(content, 0)` gives another error.

The other things I have tried so far is constructing a `pywintypes.TimeType` myself with the same value as the `DateTime.minValue` constant from the .net runtime, but that is missing timezone information (`astimezone()` error).

I tried several ways to add timezone information, including passing it in the `pywintypes.TimeType` constructor and using datetimes (which can't be converted automatically by the generated COM bindings, it seems).

Another way to go would be to use explicit timestamps, parsing them from the xml, but those use milliseconds which the `datetime` module has problems with.

How can I construct a valid time type zero to pass to the COM interface? In MATLAB i could just pass a literal 0.

EDIT: I am aware of this [git repo](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py) with related code and several blog posts on the web. The code calls the onenote COM with a literal 0 as well, but I couldn't get the package to even load the COM interface.

EDIT 2: I got onepy running and it has the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old in the meantime, but nonetheless I want to show a working solution, which I found while trying to acheive something similar. The problem is that you need a timezone-aware date in order to call `astimezone()` on it, which is what the API does for some reason. To make a timezone-aware date, you have to localize it first. For example, you could modify your code as follows:

```
import datetime
import pytz

...
date = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(year = 1899, month = 12, day = 30))
oneNoteApp.UpdatePageContent(soup, date)
```

The actual problem is coming up with a suitable date to pass to to `UpdatePageContent()`. The weird choice in my answer is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34979646/5804088).

Comment: thanks. I haven't tried it yet, but it's definitely something ill check out.