# How to debug win32com call in python

Tags: c#, python, debugging, onenote, onenote-api

In order to collect output from a logging script, I would like to use [onepy](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py) to add information to a OneNote 2013 notebook. Unfortunately, the method `update_page_content()` provided by onepy doesn't work for me. To get a deeper understanding of the problem, I switched over to C#, where many online examples for the OneNote API exist and after some [trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34849720/5804088) I managed to get the following minimalistic C# example to work:

```
using System;
using OneNote = Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OneNote.Application onenoteApp = new OneNote.Application();
        string xml = "<one:Page xmlns:one=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote\" ...> ... </one:Page>";
        onenoteApp.UpdatePageContent(xml, DateTime.MinValue);
    }
}
```

The string `xml` was obtained by modification of an XML document, which was retrieved from OneNote using the `GetPageContent` method, as detailed in my linked previous question. The precise content of `xml` doesn't matter for the sake of this question, the only important thing is that above program runs without problems time after time and changes to an existing OneNote page are always performed successfully.

Going over to Python now, I tried to translate my minimalistic program without making substantial changes. My result looks as follows:

```
import win32com
import pytz
import datetime

onenote_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('OneNote.Application.15')
xml = "<one:Page xmlns:one=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote\" ...> ... </one:Page>"
date = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.fromordinal(1))
onenote_app.UpdatePageContent(xml, date)
```

I tried to put much care into using the same values for the two variables. Of course the content of the two strings `xml` is identical (copy&paste). Also, according to the VS2015 debugger, both `DateTime.MinValue` and `date` refer to the same date. When I execute the python program, however, I recieve this very unhelpful error.

```
    135         def UpdatePageContent(self, bstrPageChangesXmlIn=defaultNamedNotOptArg, dateExpectedLastModified=(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 5, 364, 0), xsSchema=2, force=False):
    136         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743816, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (7, 49), (3, 49), (11, 49)),bstrPageChangesXmlIn
--> 137             , dateExpectedLastModified, xsSchema, force)
    138 
    139     _prop_map_get_ = {

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147213296), None)
```

To my understanding, both C# and Python actually use the same library to execute their calls (both called `Microsoft OneNote 15.0 Object Library`). So **in principle** both programs should work fine. If I am not mistaken in this point, I would thus assume that Python does *something* different in its call to the library. How can I trace further what the actual problem here is? Is there maybe a way to use the built-in Python support of Visual Studio 2015 to understand the difference between the C# and the Python code better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jayongg is already pointing out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34911991/5804088), my problem is the date passed as an argument to the `UpdatePageContent()` call. However, his suggestion to pass zero as last modified date and to disable date checking as detailed in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680120.aspx#ON14DevRef_Application_PageContent) is not as straightforward as it may seem. In my answer I will detail all the pitfalls, which I encountered.

The first problem is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33262623) question. If one tries to pass for example a `datetime` object or a plain integer to `UpdatePageContent()`, then an error like the following is raised.

```
    135         def UpdatePageContent(self, bstrPageChangesXmlIn=defaultNamedNotOptArg, dateExpectedLastModified=(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 5, 364, 0), xsSchema=2, force=False):
    136         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743816, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (7, 49), (3, 49), (11, 49)),bstrPageChangesXmlIn
--> 137             , dateExpectedLastModified, xsSchema, force)
    138 
    139     _prop_map_get_ = {

ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
```

In particular, leaving the date argument blank and using the default value does not work as expected:

```
    135         def UpdatePageContent(self, bstrPageChangesXmlIn=defaultNamedNotOptArg, dateExpectedLastModified=(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 5, 364, 0), xsSchema=2, force=False):
    136         return self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1610743816, LCID, 1, (24, 0), ((8, 1), (7, 49), (3, 49), (11, 49)),bstrPageChangesXmlIn
--> 137             , dateExpectedLastModified, xsSchema, force)
    138 
    139     _prop_map_get_ = {

TypeError: must be a pywintypes time object (got tuple)
```

Apparently some internals of the python API calls are messed up. If one follows the instructions on the [onepy project page](https://github.com/varunsrin/one-py) and uses `makepy` to pre-generte the API wrapper, then one can inspect the source files responsible for these calls, but at least for me this was not very instructive. I suspect that the `InvokeTypes` method tries to put the passed date into a format, which the API can understand, but the necessary requirements are not implemented in the Python wrapper itself.

Fortunately, there is a quite simple workaround. The trick is to make the passed `datetime` object timezone-aware. To do this, one has to localize it first. This can for example be done using the `pytz` module.

```
import datetime
import pytz

date = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.fromordinal(1))
```

With this knowledge the API call works, but the COM error from my question is raised. This is where jayongg's answer comes in: I have to pass zero as last modified date (or I need to know the date, when the last modification occurred, which should also work). Now the tricky question is: What is zero?

In my C# code, this date is given by `DateTime.MinValue`, which according to Visual Studio 2015 is equal to 0001-01-01 00:00:00. The same date in Python is `datetime.datetime.fromordinal(1)`, but it still doesn't make the call work. I have to suspect that the information by Visual Studio is wrong or that some magic happens in between, maybe a type cast VSDate -> Int -> APIDate.

So how do I find out, which is the correct zero date to pass? Turns out the answer is already there, one just needs to know where to look. If one inspects in the Python API wrapper, there is a default value given for the argument in question:

```
dateExpectedLastModified=(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 5, 364, 0)
```

The same can be obtained with the following snippet.

```
>> date = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime(year=1899, month=12, day=30))
>> print(tuple(date.timetuple()))
(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 5, 364, 0)
```

And voilà , passing the variable date to the call works just fine.

```
>> onenote_app.UpdatePageContent(xml, date)
>>
```

Makes perfect sense, right? I mean, which other date would you pass instead of 1899-12-30? Actually it does make some sense. This day is one day before the zero point of the [Dublin Julian Date](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Julian_day&oldid=698805184#Variants). According to the German [Wikipedia article](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Julianisches_Datum&oldid=149128685#Weitere_julianische_Daten) this day is used by Excel as zero point for dates, so it sound plausible that OneNote does the same.

Why the one day difference? Apparently, the year 1900 is mis-treated as leap year, which it was not. Thereby 1899-12-31 is shifted to 1899-12-30, which is what the API wants. Sigh. Why are there so many different agreements on how to store dates? Oh, just to mention. Office for Mac uses 1904 as zero point. Yeah, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You error code (-2147213296) is 0x80042010, which is:

hrLastModifiedDateDidNotMatch

0x80042010

The last modified date does not match.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff966472(v=office.14).aspx

You can try passing a last modified date of 0.
From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg649853(v=office.14).aspx:
dateExpectedLastModified—(Optional) The date and time that you think the page you want to update was last modified. **If you pass a non-zero value for this parameter, OneNote proceeds with the update only if the value you pass matches the actual date and time the page was last modified**. Passing a value for this parameter helps prevent accidentally overwriting edits users made since the last time the page was modified.

Comment: You are right with your suspicion that the date passed is the problem. Meanwhile I got the python program running and will add my solution as an answer as soon as I find the time to do it. However, you do not reply to my more general question: How do you know that -2147213296 means 0x80042010? The two numbers do not seem related to me. At least converting -2147213296 to hex gives me 0x7ffbdff0, which appears completely unrelated.

Comment: actually it gives you -0x7ffbdff0 (negative number). You need to convert it positive. You do it by adding 0x100000000 to the result.

Comment: This is true, but appears arbitrary to me. I could also add 0xffffffff and obtain a different result, for example. Is it a general rule to add 0x100000000, which is **always** true? Also, why ist there nothing to add for positive return values?

Comment: It is not arbitrary.  Adding 0x100000000 (and throwing away the carried bit) is how you can convert from a signed 32-bit integer to an unsigned integer.